# jquery ui button decoration not working with clone(true) and remove()

Tags: jquery, user-interface, button, clone

So I have simplified my example down to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ihe/resources/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ihe/resources/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ihe/resources/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(".addSectionRow").button().click(function() 
    {   
        var prevTR = $(this).closest("tr[id^='SECTION_ROW_']");
        var newTR = prevTR.clone(true, true);
        newTR.attr("id", "SECTION_ROW_1");
        prevTR.after(newTR);
    });

    $(".deleteSectionRow").button().click(function() 
    {
        var rowToRemove = $(this).closest("tr[id^='SECTION_ROW_']");
        rowToRemove.remove();
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="SECTION_TABLE">
    <tr id="SECTION_ROW_0">
        <td><div class="addSectionRow">Add</div></td>
        <td><div class="deleteSectionRow">Remove</div></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you click the add button it will add a row correctly. Now click the remove button on the row you just added and then you will see my issue. The first row looses its ui button decoration.

If I change the javascript to do this instead:

```
$(".addSectionRow").button().live("click", function() 
    {   
        var prevTR = $(this).closest("tr[id^='SECTION_ROW_']");
        var newTR = prevTR.clone();
        newTR.attr("id", "SECTION_ROW_1");
        prevTR.after(newTR);
    });

    $(".deleteSectionRow").button().live("click", function() 
    {
        var rowToRemove = $(this).closest("tr[id^='SECTION_ROW_']");
        rowToRemove.remove();
    });
```

Then the button decoration stays...but the newly added row gets stuck with the orange hover color and doesn't change back when you are no longer hovering over it.

If worse comes to worse I will just use images for these buttons. I was just wondering if I am missing something. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I need to do to fix one or both of these issues?

Comment: I used that latest version of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but I got it working by just replacing the span with a new one then adding the button decoration to the newly added span...lame I know, but if you can come up with something better I would love to hear it:

```
var prevTR = $(this).closest("tr[id^='SECTION_ROW_']");
var newTR = prevTR.clone();

var addButton = newTR.find(".addSectionRow");
var addButtonParent = addButton.parent("td");
addButtonParent.html("<span class='addSectionRow'>"+addButton.text()+"</span>");
addButtonParent.find(".addSectionRow").button();

var deleteButton = newTR.find(".deleteSectionRow");
var deleteButtonParent = deleteButton.parent("td");
deleteButtonParent.html("<span class='deleteSectionRow'>"+deleteButton.text()+"</span>");
deleteButtonParent.find(".deleteSectionRow").button();

prevTR.after(newTR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newTR.attr("id", "SECTION_ROW_1");
```

Every time you create a new row you assign it the same ID.  IDs should be unique.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but like I said at the top: "I have simplified my example". If you only add one row none of the rows have the same id. In my actually application I increment the id and the problem still exists. Just click it once then try and remove it and you will see the issue.